# Scraping information from site and into list?

Tags: android, jsoup

Hi I have been at this issue for a couple of day now. As part of a project I need to use JSOUP to bring product names and prices from this [eBuyer Search](http://www.ebuyer.com/search?q=car%20charger) website back into my application.

I was wondering about 3 issues, at the minute the code brings back all h1 header for product name and all prices on that page as a sentence.

1. Is there a way I can parse the information in Android to bring back an item at a time and list it and well as the product name as opposed to a block of text.
2. Once the right information is listed how would I listen to a specific click on that product and store it in say a variable?

Thank you so much for any help,

```
private class Title extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String h1,h3;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document element = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ebuyer.com/search?q=" + search ).get();

            h1 = element.body().getElementsByTag("h2").text();

            h3 = element.body().getElementsByTag("h1").text();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set title into TextView
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        textView.setText(h3);

        TextView textView2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView2.setText(h1);
    }
}
```

Code above is the method I am using JSOUP

Image below is what happens when I search for a product.

## [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code to get Title and Price of each product

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ebuyer.com/search?q=" + search).timeout(10000).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
Elements sections = doc.select("div.listing-product");
for (Element section : sections) {
    String title = section.select("h3.listing-product-title").text();
    String price = section.select("p.price").text();
    System.out.println("Title : " + title);
    System.out.println("Price : " + price);
}
```

Now use Listview to show each product when a list item click means when a product selected you can do whatever you want.
you can learn about listview from     http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html

Comment: Thank you will try this.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can fine-tune your targeting of elements. On the page you mentioned, each product is contained within an element with the class `listing-product`. Within this, the title is designated by a class `listing-product-title`, while the price is in an element with class `listing-price`.

Secondly, `getElementsBy...` methods return an `Elements` object, which is essentially an `ArrayList` of all matches. You should iterate through the list and handle each item individually.

Example:

```
Document element = Jsoup.connect("http://www.ebuyer.com/search?q=" + search ).get();
Elements products = element.body().getElementsByClass("listing-product");
for(Element product : products){
    String title = product.getElementsByClass("listing-product-title").text();
    String price = product.getElementsByClass("listing-product-price").text();
}
```

What you do with the items is up to you. I would create a POJO class to hold your product data, and add all your Products to an `ArrayList`. Then you can use the list to back an adapter for a `ListView` or `GridView` or something.